# How to send SIGTERM to a child process using boost::process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

[boost/process.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io) provides a nice mechanism to spawn and manage processes.

It provides a child.terminate() method to send SIGKILL to a child.

How would I alternatively send SIGINT or SIGTERM to a child process?

Comment: If you are on a Posix system: `kill(child.id(), SIGTERM);`. I don't think there is a portable way to do it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can do:

```
#include <boost/process/child.hpp>

pid_t pid = my_child.id ();
kill (pid, SIGINT);
```

The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html) states that `id` is a private member function, but in practise it seems not to be.

There's also:

`native_handle_t native_handle() const;`

But what that actually returns isn't documented.  On Windows it's most likely a process handle, but on *nix there's no such thing of course.

... And Ted beat me to it :)

Comment: :-) I just found `Windows\System32\TASKKILL.EXE /PID <pid>` that may be of use on Windows machines. I have no idea how it does it in code though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It does?  In the page I linked to, I found it lurking under 'child private member functions'.  But it makes no sense for it to be private, so maybe that's just an oversight. Edit: Oh sorry, just read your updated comment.  We are in agreement then.

Comment: I was looking [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/process/child.html) and there it only has `public:` members (but an erroneous comment about "private")

Comment: @TedLyngmo Windows does have the concept of process IDs.   `OpenProcess` takes a process ID and returns a process handle.  Once you have that, you can kill it (if you have sufficient privileges - you need to be running 'elevated` I believe).

Comment: Yes, but `TASKKILL.EXE` does not kill it unconditionally (with `TerminateProcess`) unless `/F`is used. It does "something" to signal the process to close itself (perhaps it uses `SendMessage`) so the program goes through the normal shutdown procedure. "Do you want to save..." etc.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @TedLyngmo and PaulSanders. Using your feedback I was able to fix a nasty bug. I learned that kill(0, SIGTERM), would send SIGTERM to all processes in the same group as the master process. Boost couldn't kill the children, because they were ignoring SIGKILL.

Comment: @WilderField You can also do `kill(-child.id(), SIGTERM);` to send the signal to all processes in the same process group as `child` which is probably more correct since any process can detach itself from the parent process and start a process group of its own if it wishes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Re `TASKKILL`: Ah yes, I forgot about that.  Without `/F` it probably just calls `PostMessage (hSomeWindowThatImNotSureHowItIsDerived, WM_QUIT, ...);`  (don't wanna hang the sending app!)  Once upon a time, I read one of Raymond Chen's blog posts about how Task Manager does it, but now I can't find it.